# React Router does not work on specific route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am currently developing a React web app with React router. I would want to have three routes:

1. / which is the homepage
2. /:page which is something like localhost/about.
3. /:page/:subpage which is something like /services/video

   ```
               ReactDOM.render(
               <Provider store={store}>
               <Router history={browserHistory}>
               <Route path="/(:page)(/:subpage)" component={AppContainer}/>
               </Router>
               </Provider>
               , document.getElementById("target"));
   ```

   The component is the same for all the routes. I just select the data that I pass down in the props in the render method.

The first two routes work, but /services/video doesn't if I put the url in the browser. I just get an empty page. I also have a Link element on my main page. When I click it, the desired page loads just fine and the url is actually http://localhost/services/video. However, if I reload the page I get an empty page again.

All this works fine for the first two routes, only the third one fails. The Express server that I use to serve the static html page is this:
let express = require("express");

```
let app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

A couple interesting things I have noticed: 
When I use the navigation bar with the  components I get to /services/video, but images are not found/shown. However, when I go to /about images are shown. Now when I navigate to /services/video and then I use the menu to navigate to /about the link actually becomes http://localhost:3000/services/services/about which is incorrect,it shows the correct page though, but without images again.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and the thing was a trailing slash in my case. The route definition had one, and my URL didn't, so I got an empty page (on a webserver this would be 404).

Comment: Thanks, but that does not seem to  resolve my problem.